# how add GridPane on TableView in javafx

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

i have GridPane Objects like

```
GridPane gridPane1 = new GridPane();
gridPane1.add(label1, 0, 0);
gridPane1.add(label2, 1, 0);
gridPane1.add(label3, 0, 1);
gridPane1.add(label4, 1, 1);
```

and

```
 GridPane gridPane2 = new GridPane();
    gridPane2.add(label1, 0, 0);
    gridPane2.add(label2, 1, 0);
    gridPane2.add(label3, 0, 1);
    gridPane2.add(label4, 1, 1);
```

Now How can i add this object to tableView  of javafx.?

Comment: what do you mean with add? do you want a tableview with two columns and one row containing two gridpanes? please clarify.

Comment: yes... you got my point.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that JavaFX TableView doesn't actually work like a grid where you can add arbitrary objects into it. Rather, a TableView is a way of displaying POJOs in rows, where the visual appearance of the contents of a single cell are determined by CellFactories in the TableColumn. Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) to understand how a TableView works.

That said, i propose to use a different approach to your request: Add both GridPanes into a HBox and style the HBox so it looks like a table or the like (this works easily via css). If you really want to use a TableView, the solution would be to use a POJO with two properties: the first GridPane and the second Gridpane. Then use two TableColumn cell factories which return the appropriate GridPane of the POJO, this way you hardcode those things into your TableView.